# Bit column keeps getting converted to Boolean when exporting data into CSV from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database, postgresql, csv, migration

So I have a table in SQL Server that has a column with a bit datatype with values stored as 1 or 0, the issue is when I export the table into a CSV file the data gets stored as boolean i.e. 'true' or 'false'. What I want to do is migrate this table to Postgres where the data for the matching column needs to be a bit (1 or 0). How do I stop SQL Server from storing bit values as boolean 'true'/'false' when it's exported to CSV?

Edit: Forgot to mention, the tool I'm using to export the CSV is DBCrane, however, I get the same result when using SQL Server Management Studio to export the CSV, which is that it still exports bit columns as boolean.

Comment: What tool are you using to export the data to CSV format?

Comment: It is the tool you are using, not SQL Server, that converts the bit value to the True/False string for the CSV. Add the tool to your question. If the tool doesn't have an option to control the CSV format but supports a SELECT query source, you could probably CAST the bit to integer in the query to coerce a 0/1/NULL value.

Comment: I have used two tools one is SQL Server Management Studio however it still exports bit columns as boolean, my main tool for migration is some obscure tool called DBCrane. @DanGuzman

Comment: The SSMS export data wizard allows you to specify a source query so you can specify a query like `SELECT CAST(YourBitColumn AS int) AS YourBitColumn, SomeColumn FROM dbo.YourTable;`